# How to read uppercase characters, lowercase characters, whitespace character and punctuation characters from a text file using the get function?

Tags: file, get

I am writing a program to read alphanumeric characters, uppercase characters, whitespace characters and punctuation characters and am having a bit of trouble. Here is my program I am trying to read from.

```
include iostream

include ctype.h

include stdio.h

include fstream

using namespace std;

int main(){

char ch;

int charCount = 0, upperCount = 0, punctCount = 0, whiteCount = 0;

ifstream file;

file.open("file.txt");          // open file

while (!file.eof()){            //while its not the end of the file

ch = file.get();        //get ch from the file

if (isalpha(ch)){           //if its an alphabetic character

charCount++;}           //add one to character count

else if (isupper(ch)){          //if its an uppercase letter

upperCount++;}          //add one to uppercase count

else if (ispunct(ch)){          //if its a punctuation character

punctCount++;}          //add one to punctuation count

else{                   //else its a whitespace character

whiteCount++;}          //add one to blank count

ch++;                   //increment the character

}                   //end while

file.close();               //close file

cout << "The number of alphabetic characters is: " << charCount << endl;

cout << "The number of uppercase characters is: " << upperCount << endl;

cout << "The number of punctuation characters is: " << punctCount << endl;

cout << "The number of whitespace characters is: " << whiteCount << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: For writing better questions: when writing your question, you can use the curly bracket icon at the top of the text field for writing code. Makes reading code a lot easier.

Comment: For the question itself: First of all, does it compile? If so, are actually getting the file? I noticed you put no diamond brackets (<>) around your includes, that can be an issue.

Comment: You might consider adding the tag `c++` to your question so more users will be drawn to the page.